# lock-ddl-per-table option not working as expected in Xtrabackup

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.7, ddl

I've recently been getting the following errors on some of my Percona XtraBackup backups:

```
InnoDB: An optimized (without redo logging) DDL operation has been performed. All modified pages may not have been flushed to the disk yet.
```

However, it was my understanding that this should be avoided by including the `--lock-ddl-per-table` option.

The script I use is as follows:

```
xtrabackup ${MySQLConnectionString} --backup --parallel=${CPUCount} --compress --compress-threads=${CPUCount} --throttle=${throttle} --slave-info --extra-lsndir="${LogsDir}" --target-dir="${CurrentDir}" --lock-ddl-per-table


xtrabackup ${MySQLConnectionString} --backup --parallel=${CPUCount} --compress --compress-threads=${CPUCount} --throttle=${throttle} --slave-info --extra-lsndir="${LogsDir}" --target-dir="${NewDir}" --incremental-basedir="${BaseDir}" --lock-ddl-per-table
```

My Databases are all MySQL 5.7.28, and they are slave databases. They are all running on Debian 9, and using PXB version 2.4.16.

Have I misunderstood the usage of this option?

Answer (score 0):

How about [xtrabackup 2.4.21](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/release-notes/2.4/2.4.21.html), which redesigns [`--lock-ddl-per-table`](https://jira.percona.com/browse/PXB-2254)?

See also https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/12/22/redesign-of-lock-ddl-per-table-in-percona-xtrabackup/